# getting form value from the same php page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a database and I get info from it and put it into php page. BUT the thing is, I cant put data from that php file to database. I use form to put there the value of variable, but it says [html span element]. and I get errors:
Notice: Undefined index: souls in xxx/the_cave.php on line 20
Notice: Undefined index: bones in xxx/the_cave.php on line 21

Here is the code:
JS:

```
document.getElementById("souls_form").value=<?php echo $souls_value; ?>;
    document.getElementById("bones_form").value=<?php echo $bones_value; ?>;
    function upload(){
        <?php upload(); ?>}
```

PHP part:

```
$current_souls=$_POST['souls'];
$current_bones=$_POST['bones'];
function upload(){
    mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE Data SET Souls=$current_souls, Bones=$current_bones WHERE Username='$username'");
```

HTML form

```
<form style="visibility:hidden" action="" method="post">
<input  name="souls" id="souls_form">
<input  name="bones" id="bones_form">
</form>
```

Comment: What's the meaning of the Javascript code?

Comment: On load I set input's value with Javascript

Comment: `text` is the default type.

Comment: still the same... Don't I need to submit the form somehow?

Comment: Through the HTML form you would pass the values. It is right?

Comment: yes, I would pass it on unload

Comment: $_POST[] should get data by submitting the form only

Comment: Yes I know this. The thing is that I get this error when page loads, not when I close the tab

Comment: I can't figure out how to make this work, sorry. All I could test with what I have to work with (and without setting up a whole DB etc.), was to use `<input  name="souls" id="souls_form" value="<?php echo $current_souls; ?>">`

Comment: nope, doesn't work. Maybe Ill ask question a bit differently: Whats the easiest way to put JS var into DB?

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("souls_form").value=<?php echo $current_souls; ?>;` ?

Comment: uhm... $current_souls shoud be a value of the input

Comment: That's what it's coming from `$current_souls=$_POST['souls'];` with `("souls_form").value=<?php echo $current_souls; ?>;` no? Have you tried it?

Comment: hey when the page loads first the php code will be executed,so there is no values in $_POST['souls'] and $_POST['bones'],got it?

Comment: what would you recommend me to avoid it?

Comment: How about I print out all PHP code with JS on unload? will it work?

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATED CODE*

```
<script>
var souls1=<?php echo $souls_value;?>
var bones1=<?php echo $bones_value;?>
//do your process
//after the values changes for variables souls1,bones1
//YOU HAVE TO CALL AJAX CALL TO SAVE YOUR UPDATED VARIABLES DATA INTO DB
$.ajax({
url:'updatedata.php',
type:"POST",
data:{souls:souls1,bones:bones1},
success:function(result)
{
if(result)
{
alert('updated succesfully');
}
}
});
```

***updatedata.php***

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['souls'])&&isset($_POST['bones']))
{
$current_souls=$_POST['souls'];
$current_bones=$_POST['bones'];
if(mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE Data SET Souls='$current_souls', Bones='$current_bones' WHERE      Username='$username'"))
{
echo 'TRUE';
}
}
?>
```

As the Php code executes first than all other codes, the `$current_souls=$_POST['souls'];` is executing first so you have to check form submission using isset() other wise no error will be printed

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? this code wont fire any errors

Comment: ummm ill try to explain as simply as I can. I got $souls_value and $bones_value from MYSQL DB. And I transform this variable into JS variable. Till this part it works ok. I can ad, subtract from those vars. So those vars change. And for example I have souls=10000 on the load of page and then when I close I have lets say 10207. And I want to put this variable in DB. So I try to use hidden form to set it value of souls(bones) and then using PHP I want to get those values and simply put it in DB

Comment: i have updated my answer once see it,if it helps then accept as a answer

Comment: One question: I need to create one more php file right?

Comment: no need if you want to put your php code in same page then give the samepage name in url:''

Comment: This time I got no errors, code works fine but somewhy DB doesn't update

Comment: change alert('updated succesfully') to alert(result); then try to print the $_POST values in php code then you will see those values in alert box,then you can get to know what are the data in the _POST

Comment: sorry I coudnt answer yesterday. Although I tested it today. I get no php errors, but DB is still not being updated. oh and by the way, one more question. do I still need those inputs? because I deleted them

Comment: i didn't understand mate,if your update query is not working then you have to see what is the query that is executing.So as the result variable in the ajax request contains all the data which we printed or echoed in the php page,so my suggestion is to print the query in the php page as echo 'the update query'; then you will see that query in the alert box as it comes from ajax response

Comment: i feel sorry asking that, but im not familiar with ajax, so would that be a problem to update your answer? I would be really thankful :)

Comment: I found a bit different solution, but anyway, thanks :)